# Eliminate coma '.' in calculator React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, calculator

This is my first question around here so thank you everybody who just spend some little time with my problem.

So here I go...

I have to design a calculator in React Native. I have pretty much everything ready but there is one detail that is killing me. How do I eliminate the possibility of adding a coma in the last space of the calculator input.

This is the function that calls the "," button on the calculator. I am from Spain and here we use "," for decimals. But in React Native is configured for american "," which is "." I believe.

```
 function CheckComa() {
        if(!InputNumber.includes(".") || InputNumber[0] == "0") {
          setInputNumber(InputNumber+ '.');
        }
        if(InputNumber[InputNumber.charAt(InputNumber.length-1)] == '.')
          setInputNumber((InputNumber= InputNumber.slice(0,numeroInput.length-1)));
    
      }
```

What I do is to check if the numbers doesnt includes , o if the first number is 0, then places the , into the number.
Second check is for last element of number. It really works because on the display it doesn't count the "," for making the calculation, but it appears on the screen. I want to avoid that.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you can try using Regex to detect/check the value.

Comment: I don't think this `InputNumber[InputNumber.charAt(InputNumber.length-1)]` does what you think it does. You should use either `InputNumber[InputNumber.length-1]` or `InputNumber.charAt(InputNumber.length-1)`

Comment: setState in React Native is asynchronous, your setState won't change your value unless the function is complete. Thats why your second `if` condition is not working.

Comment: Thank guy guys for your help. I figured it out. Basically I was forgetting to check a condition in another part of the program.